# Retrieve Cell in another Column in a CellTable

Tags: gwt

I have two Columns in a `CellTable`:

Column A contains a custom `RadioButtonGroupCell`, which extends `AbstractInputCell`. The group contains three radio buttons.

Column B contains a `ButtonCell`, and a click on the button is supposed to clear the selection made by the user in Column A.

My problem is I don't know how to retrieve a Cell in Column A from Column B. If I can retrieve the relevant Cell from Column A, I can work it out from there. Do the columns share a parent `Element` I can work with? I don't know the 'best practice' to follow and would be grateful for any tips.

---

Fixed as follows:

```
Element element = (Element) cellTable.getRowElement(rowIndex);
InputElement inputElement = (InputElement) element;
inputElement.setChecked(false);
cellTable.redraw();
```

---

Hmm, cellTable.redraw() deselects all radio buttons in all rows. Needs more work .....

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current selected row (object by using following line)

cellTable.getDisplayedItems().get(index)

Once you get the object, set its value 
   cellTable.getDisplayedItems().get(index).SET...

Once value is Set , redraw the table

cellTable.redraw();

Hope this helps....

Comment: Thanks for your answer Saket, in the end I fixed this as shown in the edit to my original post.