# add property to Cell (in code)

Tags: java, gwt, cell, placeholder, gxt

I'm using GWT primarily in code. I currently have a column with a TextInputCell:

```
public class EditPanel extends Composite{

    @UiField
    protected DataGrid<MyObject> dataGrid;

    public EditPanel(final ActionHandler actionHandler){
        ...

        Column<MyObject, String> inputColumn = new Column<MyObject, String>(new TextInputCell()){
            ... // Override of the getValue
        };
        inputColumn.setFieldUpdater(...);
        this.dataGrid.addColumn(inputColumn, "Column title");

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450987/how-to-add-a-placeholder-to-a-gwt-text-input-field/10451912#10451912) I know I can add a placeholder-text (or any other property) to a regular TextField in GWT like this:

```
TextField myInputField = new TextField();
myInputField.getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder", "some placeholder text");
```

However, on the TextInputCell there isn't really a `getElement()` method to retrieve the input-field.

When looking through the TextInputCell-class code I came across the `protected getInputElement(parent)` method, so I did managed to get a placeholder with the following work-around:

```
final TextInputCell myInputCell = new TextInputCell(){

    @Override
    protected InputElement getInputElement(final Element parent){
        final InputElement inputElement = super.getInputElement(parent);
        inputElement.setPropertyString("placeholder", "my placeholder text");
        return inputElement;
    }
};
Column<MyObject, String> inputColumn = new Column<MyObject, String>(myInputCell){
    ...
};
```

It works, but I have two concerns:

1. Obviously it is very ugly to set it like this..
2. The `getInputElement(parent)`-method isn't called initially. I do get the placeholder when I focus one of the input-field, but the property is not always added by default..

Does anyone have an actual solution of how to add a Property to the (TextInput)Cell of a Column, instead of this ugly *maybe*-working work-around?

---

EDIT: Some things I've tried:

1) Trying to retrieve the element with the `getRowElement` method, like in [this SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886489/retrieve-cell-in-another-column-in-a-celltable):

```
this.dataGrid.addColumn(inputColumn, "Column title");
if (this.dataGrid.getRowCount() > 0){
    final Element element = this.dataGrid.getRowElement(0);
    element.setProperty("placeholder", "some placeholder text");
}
```

This doesn't work because `getRowCount()` always returns 0. I also tried a `this.dataGrid.redraw();` right before it, but it still returns 0.

2) Overriding the `TextInputCell` as *geert3* suggested:

```
public class MyTextInputCell extends TextInputCell{

    @Override
    public InputElement getInputElement(Element parent){
        return super.getInputElement(parent);
    }
}
```

The problem? I don't know what to put in for the parent-parameter. I did try `this.getElement()`:

```
MyTextInputCell textInputCell = new MyTextInputCell();
Column<MyObject, String> inputColumn = new Column<MyObject, String>(textInputCell){
    ... // Override of the getValue
};
inputColumn.setFieldUpdater(...);
this.dataGrid.addColumn(inputColumn, "Column title");
textInputCell.getInputElement(this.getElement()).setPropertyString("placeholder", "some placeholder text");
```

but that doesn't seem to work. And when I try `this`,  `this.dataGrid` or `inputColumn` it gives an error because they aren't considered as `Elements` (and I also can't cast them).

3) Using my initial work-around.

Problem: I can't really find a way to enforce the `getInputElement(parent)` method call when the page loads, instead of when an input-field is focused.

Pretty annoying that there is no way to directly access the InputFields of a `TextInputCell` in GWT...

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading up a bit on Cells. These are in fact reused, a single Cell can render multiple DOM instances of itself, and it can handle events from multiple rendered instances. This means that a Cell doesn't have a one-to-one associated Element, but receives the "current" element as it is being reused, passed as the "parent" argument to several methods.

So in conclusion I think this means that the original solution you've described in your question appears to be a valid solution, not "ugly" at all.